# How to add image or logo in Unity C# script to show on Inspector Window?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor, inspector

I am trying to add an **image/logo** in my own script like the example below. Searched a lot in Google and Unity forum but nothing found straight to me. I want to add an image/logo of my own in my script so that it will show up in the top of my script in **inspector window**.
See the example below marked with red marker.

Here is my example code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour {

public int speed = 20;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't have to bold every text in all your Unity questions. Post your Inspector script so that we will know where you need help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DrawPreviewTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.DrawPreviewTexture.html) and supply it with your logo. You could load your texture from Resources.

Comment: Solved the problem, I need to create an Editor script for this purpose. The perfect example I found here : https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/adding-buttons-custom-inspector